# AG-GRID cell only shows error border and tooltip after 2nd edit

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I'm having some issues with Ag-grid and can't really understand the issue.
I'm using cellValueChanged event to pass a Validation function to the cell.

The issue is that on the first time a user edits the cell it runs the validation function but does not mark the cell as "with error" ( red border and tooltip ). All edits after the first edit run fine, showing the red border and tooltip if the cell has an error.

```
CustomGrid.GridObject[CustomGrid.TemporaryVariables.arrPos].gridOptions.api.addEventListener('cellValueChanged', function(e) { 
    CustomGrid.ValidationFeature.validation(e);
});

CustomGrid.ValidationCtrl.validation = function (params) {
    if(CustomGrid.DirtyCellCtrl.isCellDirty(params) && params.colDef.Validation) {
        params.colDef.Validation.call({}, params);
    }
};
```

Note: CustomGrid.DirtyCellCtrl.isCellDirty is a custom helper function to check if cell has a different valid value and returns true/false. For this case admit it always returns true.

Any help or hints will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try having a look at api.refreshCells() and api.redrawRows(). Maybe you could share a plunk or fiddle which shows the issue as well .

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Helped me track down the issue. It turned out that the params being passed to the refreshCells() were incorrect thus refreshCells wasn't doing anything.